# How to handle a reopen when changed into a good question for a different problem?

Tags: support, review-queues, vote-to-reopen

Working through the reopen queue, I encountered a question that was correctly closed, and (after editing) it became a reasonable question. But I feel that the topic has changed considerably. It's just not the same question anymore

First it was a question about debugging a script in console, the revision is about dispatching/triggering javascript events.
See these revisions: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45368041/revisions

It might be something like an XY problem, or this  is just the next step after the first issue was resolved, but in those cases it might be better to just open an new question? This seems a strange method to go about your closed question.

Looking at the final question it didn't seem like a bad question anymore, so I voted reopen; But what do you think? Is "this is a different question" even a case or is it just "the final product is ok, so vote based on that"?

Comment: We should note the guidance given to users whose questions are put on hold for being unclear: "If this question can be reworded to fit the rules in the help center, please edit the question."

Comment: I'm sorry if I didn't get your meaning, but I read that as meaning that you are still asking about the same problem, but with a different question / wording. In this case, the whole problem has been changed, and that is just not how I interpreted editting a question. I'm not saying it's wrong, it's just unexpected for me to improve a question by changing the complete problem.

Comment: I was just providing that as a reminder to those who want to provide an answer.

Comment: Ah, ok! Sorry, I indeed misread your comment. Don't mind me then :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is "this is a different question" even a case or is it just "the final product is ok, so vote based on that"?

No, it doesn't matter what the original question was. Why should it? The original question failed to meet our guidelines and was put on hold. The whole point of putting a question "on hold" is so it can be edited into shape. The person did that, so don't punish them for it!

**All that matters is the final product.** Look at that, and that alone. Is it a valid, on-topic question for the site? If so, vote to re-open. If not, vote to leave it closed.

The only time this should really bother you is if you see a *pattern* of behavior from the same user, where they are going through all of their old questions and drastically rewriting them. This smells suspiciously like someone who is trying to evade an automatic question ban. You should pick one of their questions at random and flag for moderator attention, explaining your concerns in the provided freeform text box.

When I read the title, what I *thought* you were going to ask was what to do when a question is drastically rewritten such that it should now be closed for a *different reason*. That's a bit trickier. While it would probably goes against the obsessive-compulsive tendencies of many of our members (including myself!), the proper choice in such cases is still to vote for leaving the question closed. There's no good way to *change* the close reason. You'd have to re-open it and close it again, which takes too long, requires the involvement of too many people, and is too error-prone. It's better to have a problematic question closed for the wrong reason than to have it open and accepting answers.

Comment: This was what I thought was the case and how I acted, so I agree :) I'll see if I can fix the title a bit for clarity

Comment: (also, checked this case and it doesn't seem to involve any pattern, so no extra moderator attention is warranted)

Comment: I don't think the original title was *unclear*, @Nanne. I was just trying to anticipate what might have been going through your head, based on past experiences. :-)

Comment: I think you forgot to mention that radical edits should not invalidate existing answers (granted in the case of the question discussed here it doesn't have answers at all so this check "passes")

Comment: I agree with @gnat's note...the above answer is fine, but should be improved by addressing the possibility that a poor question may still have seen some attempts at answering, and those answers may fit the extent of what was comprehensible of the original question. Bottom line: as a question garners feedback from users, that feedback will tend to constrain how much the original question can be edited before such edits invalidate the feedback and thus should in fact be presented as a completely new question.

Comment: @PeterDuniho, You say feedback instead of answers. That *implies* you're including comments as "feedback" which should not be invalidated. I disagree. Comments are ephemeral. Invalidating them is not a problem. To clean them up, they can be flagged as no longer needed. In fact, many comments are explicitly intended to be invalidated when their suggestions for improvements / requests for additional information are resolved by editing the question to make the improvements or provide more info. Yes, completely changing the question may invalidate all comments, but that's not inherently bad.

Comment: It's a valid point everyone is making, but I'm not convinced that invalidating existing answers is a significant issue when the question has been *closed*. This is a risk you take when answering low-quality questions waiting to be closed.